# Intercambiar posiciones arreglo c++

Tags: c++

amigos de la comunidad, no logro hacer que mi código funcione bien, lo que quiero hacer es que esto se cumpla:

[1][2][3][4][5][6]

[6][5][4][3][2][1]

y este es lo que llevo, alguna idea?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x[20];

    cout << "\n Valores a ingresar :\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << "(" << i + 1 << "/6): ";
        cin  >> x[i];
    }

    int temp;
    for(int i = 1; i <6 - 1; i++) {
        temp = x[i-1];
        x[i-1] = x[i+1];
        x[i+1] = temp;
    }

    cout << "\nLos datos cambiados son: ";
    for(int i = 0; i <6; i++)
        cout << x[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está en las operaciones que realizas; no es simplemente `x - 1` y `x + 1`; es `tamaño - i - 1`.
Y tampoco hay que recorrer el *array* completo: solo hasta la mitad.

Te dejo el código resuelto, con algunas salidas a pantalla para que veas lo que pasa:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {
    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    int size = sizeof( x ) / sizeof( x[0] );

    const int half = size / 2;
cout << "half: " << half << '\n';

    for( int idx = 0; idx < half; ++idx ) {
cout << size - idx - 1 << ", " << idx << "( " << x[size - idx - 1] << " <-> " << x[idx] << " )\n";
        int tmp = x[size - idx - 1];
        x[size - idx - 1] = x[idx];
        x[idx] = tmp;
    }

    cout << "\nLos datos cambiados son: ";
    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        cout << x[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ese código genera:

> half: 3
> 6, 0( 7 <-> 1 )
> 5, 1( 6 <-> 2 )
> 4, 2( 5 <-> 3 )
>
> Los datos cambiados son: 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Puedes hacer pruebas simplemente aumentando o disminuyendo el número de elementos en el *array*; por ejemplo, para

```
int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
```

genera:

> half: 5
> 9, 0( 10 <-> 1 )
> 8, 1( 9 <-> 2 )
> 7, 2( 8 <-> 3 )
> 6, 3( 7 <-> 4 )
> 5, 4( 6 <-> 5 )

Los datos cambiados son: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

Comment: Amgio gracias, fuiste de mucha ayuda, Dios te bendiga.